# Ms Word Text to binary

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to convert a Ms Word file's text to binary and store it in database. I have managed to open up the file and TrackRevisions also. How can I save the MS word text in database and retrieve it back and show it in MS Word

Comment: SQL Server?  Which version?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the file content  to a binary/varbinary field (The max length allowed in SQL Server is 8000).

Use Parameters to insert/update the database. Here a c# example :

[Storing Text file into MS SQL database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/vsx/thread/01eef4b1-cd2e-4095-8a4c-b971dd9a33b2)

```
//reading the file content
FileStream s = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];
s.Read(buffer, 0, s.Length);
s.Close();

//adding a row in the database
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("insertCommand into myTable (binaryField) values (@filedata)", youconnection);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter ("@filedata", buffer ));
insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

[Retrieving msword file loaded as binary data in sql server database](http://forums.asp.net/t/1295427.aspx/1)

Comment: Please summarize the contents of the links in your answer.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231

Comment: How does it work? I need to store just the text of it and if changes made then while saving the whole modified data should get saved in the database. Basically I don't want to download the file. Just want to give the user the facility to open,edit and restore back the file in DB

Comment: @Ankur: Keep in mind that this is a programming website, so the answers you get are most likely going to be code.

Comment: +1. @Ankur, the code to save to DB is present and one to read is linked. If you don't understand the code it may be good idea to read about each class/method used first - there is way more than one sentence to explain the sample.